# How do I check if two vectors are equal using a function?

Tags: python, numpy, function, vector, equality

I am attempting to check if two vectors are equal using a function. I don't know if I am using the correct function because I am not getting true or false as a return. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4])

y=np.array([1,2,3,4])

def check(x,y):

    if x == y:
        print("They are equal")
```

When I run the code, it does not return anything so I am assuming it is not running the if statement. Am I writing the function correctly or what should I adjust?

Comment: Call `check(x, y)`.

Comment: Yes, as @Guimoute note, you just define the function `check`, however, you did not call it.  You need to call it at then end of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the NumPy array equal you can use [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html). And it's better to practice using `return` for function instead of printing the result.

```
def check(x,y):
    if np.array_equal(x,y):
        return "They are equal"
    return "Not equal"
```

Execution:

```
print(check(x,y))
# They are equal
```

Comment: I completely forgot to use return instead. Also, np.array_equal is alot easier. Thank you!